# Flot chart pie tooltip not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I use exactly the same code as in this example [Chart fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rnusy/335/)

```
datapie = [
    {label: "Running",  data: [19.5, 1], color: '#e1ab0b'},
    {label: "Stopped",  data: [4.5, 2], color: '#fe0000'},
    {label: "Terminated",  data: [36.6, 3], color: '#93b40f'}
];

function legendFormatter(label, series) {
    return '<div ' + 
           'style="font-size:8pt;text-align:center;padding:2px;">' +
           label + ' ' + Math.round(series.percent)+'%</div>';
};

$.plot($("#placeholder"), datapie, {

 series: {
     pie: {show: true, threshold: 0.1
        // label: {show: true}
    }
    },
     grid: {
        hoverable: true
    },
    tooltip: true,
    tooltipOpts: {
        cssClass: "flotTip",
        content: "%x %y %p.0 %s",
        shifts: {
            x: 20,
            y: 0
        },
        defaultTheme: false
    },


    legend: {show: true, labelFormatter: legendFormatter}

    });
```

Chart works, is hoverable but tooltip does not show up.

I have been using local copies of js scripts, tried also with ones from cloud flare [Cdn links](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot.tooltip/0.9.0/jquery.flot.tooltip.js)

Any suggestion what might went wrong and how to debug this?

UPDATE:
Import scripts I use and their order:

```
<script src="/Vendor/Flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="/Vendor/flot.tooltip/js/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Vendor/Flot/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>
```

I have been testing with this one as well, commenting beforehand the first
`tooltip` import and putting this one at the end. Same behaviour, no success. All pie graphs work fine, therefore I have not tested cdn scripts other than `tooltip`.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot.tooltip/0.9.0/jquery.flot.tooltip.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please show how you import script files for your code and libs.

Comment: @DimaMamchur Question updated.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with your same code on jsfiddle, did work. Btw flot tooltip cdn link should be after flot main script.

However you can use function on content, try following code:

```
content: function(label, xval, yval, flotItem) {
   return label  + ' x:' + xval + ' y: ' + yval;
},
```

[image]

Here are important things to note on tooltip content:

HTML tags are also allowed; use %s for series label, `%x for X value, %y for Y value and %p for percentage` value.

With `%x, %y and %p` values you can also use .precision, for example %x.2 means that value of X will be rounded to 2 digits after the decimal point.

If no precision or dateFormat is set then plugin uses tickFormatter to format values displayed on tooltip.

If you require even more control over how the tooltip is generated you can pass a callback function(label, xval, yval, flotItem) that must return a string with the format described.

you can find more information [here](https://github.com/krzysu/flot.tooltip).

Comment: `%x %y` are not recognised by the tooltip library, thus displayed just as a text. I have double checked removing `%x %y` - still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's working snippet. Please pay attention to the order in which scripts are loaded - you can try and import your local files in the same way. Your javascript should go after the `<body>`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://envato.stammtec.de/themeforest/melon/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://envato.stammtec.de/themeforest/melon/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.pie.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot.tooltip/0.9.0/jquery.flot.tooltip.js"></script>
  <style>
    .flotTip {
      padding: 3px 5px;
      background-color: #000;
      z-index: 100;
      color: #fff;
      opacity: .80;
      filter: alpha(opacity=85);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="placeholder" style="width:500px;height:400px;"></div>

</body>
<script>
  datapie = [{
      label: "Running",
      data: 19.5,
      color: '#e1ab0b'
    },
    {
      label: "Stopped",
      data: 4.5,
      color: '#fe0000'
    },
    {
      label: "Terminated",
      data: 36.6,
      color: '#93b40f'
    }
  ];

  function legendFormatter(label, series) {
    return '<div ' +
      'style="font-size:8pt;text-align:center;padding:2px;">' +
      label + ' ' + Math.round(series.percent) + '%</div>';
  };

  $.plot($("#placeholder"), datapie, {

    series: {
      pie: {
        show: true,
        threshold: 0.1
        // label: {show: true}
      }
    },
    grid: {
      hoverable: true
    },
    tooltip: true,
    tooltipOpts: {
      cssClass: "flotTip",
      content: "%p.0%, %s",
      shifts: {
        x: 20,
        y: 0
      },
      defaultTheme: false
    },


    legend: {
      show: true,
      labelFormatter: legendFormatter
    }

  });
</script>

</html>
```